# Permission denied: '/code/celerybeat.pid'

Tags: django, docker, celery

I can't run Celery beat using Docker.

```
celerybeat_1    | celery.platforms.LockFailed: [Errno 13] Permission 
denied: '/code/celerybeat.pid'
```

docker service:

```
celerybeat:
 <<: *django
 depends_on:
  - postgres
  - redis
 command: /start-celerybeat.sh
```

start-celerybeat.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

celery -A my_project.taskapp beat -l info --loglevel=debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete that file. Then, modify the last line of start-celerybeat.sh, adding `--pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid` to the end

Comment: Just to build on this answer. Celery beat produces 2 files typically (a pid file and a celerybeat-schedule or local database file). You may need to explicitly state where you want these to live. For the pid file use the above recommendation: --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid, for the celerybeat-schedule file use -s /tmp/celerybeat-schedule. Here is the relevant documentation: https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler

Comment: @TaylorD you should have posted this as an answer (not a comment). It solved my issue. Thanks!